# proof involving double complement

Tags: proof-writing

Prove  $(A^c)^c$ = $A$

$(A^c)^c = \{x|x\in (A^c)^c\}$

$(A^c)^c = \{x|x\notin A^c\}$ by definition of complement

$(A^c)^c = \{x|\ (x \in A)\}$ by definition of complement

Therefore

$(A^c)^c=A$

Is this proof ok, I'm not sure if its valid? thanks

Comment: It might be worth attempting the direct proof, i.e. showing $(A^c)^c \subseteq A$ and vice versa.

Comment: oh ok, is this one not valid then

Comment: Your proof is fine.

Comment: Remark: it's spelled complement when you use it in this context.

Comment: oh I see, thanks!